# Why was this edit approved?

Tags: discussion, editing

[This edit](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/revisions/2322/3) seems to add nothing to the question, but it was approved by community.

Why was it approved?

Comment: It appears I was one of the culprits in this.  If you haven't rolled back and edit before, you can now.  As well, you get a badge for it.  Sorry if I confused things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From Meta SE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) it says that the community user

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> ...
>
> **Own suggested edits from anonymous users**

So the edit was suggested by an anonymous user.

Answer (score 1):

Community is a bot and has a 'mind' of it's own.

It does exhibit interesting behavior.  I wish we could ask it why.

Perhaps asking in SO Meta may yield a more educated response from the dev team.

Comment: If I'm looking at the edit correctly, it was proposed by "anonymous" and approved by your (Ducati) and "race fever" about 21 hours ago, though MooseLucifer declined it. [Check this link at the top](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/16116) to see what I mean.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yes, see that now.  I think I approved because the words "heater core" would make it more searchable.  At least, that was logic my head assigned to my right handed index finger when I clicked.

Comment: Ahh, I wasn't thinking about search-ability, I declined it for the same reason listed in the question, the wording made no sense and didn't seem to clarify the question.

Comment: If you ask the 'bot on Meta, maybe it will reply.